# Understanding of conditional expectation as a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation, conditional-expectation

On page 3 of Knuth's [Pre-Fascicle 5A (Mathematical Preliminaries Redux)](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/fasc5a2015.10.03.pdf) of TAOCP, it reads:

> ... you might think of $E(X \mid Y)$ as a function of $Y$. Well, yes; but the best way to understand $E(X \mid Y)$ is to regard it as a *random variable*.

and

> All random variables are functions of the atomic events $\omega$. The value of $E(X \mid Y)$ at $\omega$ is the average of $X(w')$ over all events $\omega'$ such that $Y(\omega') = Y(\omega)$:
>   $$E(X \mid Y)(\omega) = \sum_{w' \in \Omega} X(\omega') \Pr(\omega')[Y(\omega') = Y(\omega)]/\Pr(Y = Y(\omega)).$$

How to understand the formula for $E(X \mid Y)(\omega)$?

Specifically, ***is it a definition or is it derivable from some basic facts and definitions?*** Why does it involve all $\omega'$  such that $Y(\omega') = Y(\omega)$?

Furthermore, suppose that $Y(\omega) = y$, I find that 
$$E(X \mid Y)(\omega) = E(X \mid Y = y),$$
according to the formula above.

Is it correct? If so, how to understand it,
for example, ***from the perspective of function composition***?

Answer (score 1):

The formula for $E(X|Y)(\omega)$ is given and is clearly a function of $X(\omega)$ and $Y(\omega)$. Thus it is a function of another random variable and hence a random variable itself. This *random variable* represents conditional expectation. The formula gives you a way to compute it as well.

The formula states that the conditional expectation (*random variable* $E(X|Y)$) is given as the probability weighted sum of the random variable $X(\omega')$ on all $\omega'$ for which holds $Y(\omega')=Y(\omega)$ or in other words by the formula
$$E(X|Y)(\omega)=\sum_{\omega' \in \Omega}X(\omega') Pr(\omega'|Y(\omega))$$

Comment: Thanks. Is the formula for $E(X | Y)(\omega)$ a definition or derivable from other basic facts and definitions? Why does it involve all $\omega'$  such that $Y(\omega') = Y(\omega)$? Can this be interpreted from the perspective of function composition? (See also the updated post.)

Comment: it is the definition of conditional expectation. One sums over all events on which the condition holds. This is the summary